# Extjs - force panel/grid to be 100% height

Tags: extjs, height

I have a simple `grid/panel` that is located under a `tab`.

I cant get it to be in `100%` height of the parent `tab`.

How do you do it?

```
height:'100%'
```

and

```
viewConfig:{ forceFit: true }
```

won't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

forceFit does not have anything to do with it.

Often the problem is that your grid need to be inside a container with a "fit" layout.

But I cannot help you more without some code.

Comment: This is correct. The tab panel containing the grid should have layout:'fit'.

Comment: @bmoeskau - the tab panel itself uses CardLayout and you wouldn't want to fiddle with that, right ? I assume you meant to nest the grid in a container that will be the direct child of the tab panel and have layout:'fit' on the container.

Comment: I meant "the panel that *is* the tab" should have layout:'fit' not the TabPanel itself. Each tab within the TabPanel is a panel and requires a layout if containing other components. Alternately the GridPanel could itself be a direct child of TabPanel (without a separate containing layer) and would then require no separate layout declaration.  I suspect the OP is doing TabPanel -> Panel (no layout) -> GridPanel.